# How to determine if a user had previously signed in with google firebase signin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

I am using google signin for my android project, and after successful authentication with firebase auth, I add user records with additional default fields to firestore.

The problem is when same user tries to signin again with same email, a new document of same user gets added to the firestore database (Two documents with same data)

I need a way to know if user had previously signed in so that I wont add a new document to firestore

I have searched Stack overflow and have only found solution for auth using email and password. The solution uses :

> authResultTask.getException() instanceof
>   FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException

which doesn't work for google signin

```
//google signin result intent
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RequestSignInCode){

            GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

            if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()){

                Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this,"Google Sign In result available ..."/* authCredential.getProvider()*/,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();

                firebaseUserAuth(googleSignInAccount);
            }
            //else Toast.makeText(this, "falsa1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        //else Toast.makeText(this, "falsa2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void firebaseUserAuth(final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {

            AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleSignInAccount.getIdToken(), null);

            mAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(WelcomeActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task AuthResultTask) {
                            Log.d("auth", "AuthResultTask:Complete ");

                                if (AuthResultTask.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.d("auth", "AuthResultTask successful");

                                    String email = googleSignInAccount.getEmail();

                                    Map<String, Object> userProperties = new HashMap<>();
                                    userProperties.put("email", email);
                                    userProperties.put("fullname", "");
                                    userProperties.put("isActivated", false);
                                    userProperties.put("has_rated", false);
                                    userProperties.put("product_key", "");
                                    userProperties.put("time_registered", new Date());
                                    userProperties.put("total_referral_count", 0);



                                    db.collection("users")
                                            .add(userProperties)
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                    Log.d("doc_id", documentReference.getId());
                                                    Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Google Sign In successful...",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    Log.w(DB_TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                }

                                            });


                                } else {
                                    Log.d("auth", "Exception: " + AuthResultTask.getException().toString());
                                    Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Something Went Wrong ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }

                    });
        }
```

Comment: To avoid having the same user sign in the second time with a different UID, remember to use `GoogleSignin.signOut();` when signing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be a lot easier for you if you use the UID of the user, assigned by Firebase Authentication, as the ID of the document instead of using the random ID created by the `add()` method.  The UID is going to be the same every time the user signs in.

```
AuthResult authResult = ...
FirebaseUser user = authResult.getUser();
// this is unique for the user
String uid = user.getUid();

// Create a document for this user using their UID
db.collection("users").document(uid).set(userProperties);
```

You might also want to check if the document already exists first before trying to write it like this, or use a merge set to overwrite its existing contents.

Comment: FirebaseUser user = authResult.getResult().getUser();

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to create document when the user first signs up. So you have to submit the document after the user signs up. Not after every login.